# Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Tags: java, android, xml, logcat

App crashed because

```
Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

My gradle

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile 'com.yalantis:contextmenu:1.0.7'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'org.litepal.android:core:1.5.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.1'
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

It is xml code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Here is part of my logcat.......

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2196)
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)

I failed to upload my total logcat.Whatever I did,there always was an error in  editting.(By the way,I use Android Studio 2.3  ...)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add to the project the correct library.

Go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order and export tab. Set android-support-v4.jar library checked and up it into top of the list.

Clean and rebuild it, it should works.

Comment: I use Android Studio.How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In android studio you need to add line

```
   implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
```

to your build file